# User defined function : insert into a table statement forbidden

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, user-defined-functions

I'd like to write a ud-function in my SQL database in order to write procedure logging in a specific table among dbo tables.

I'd like this specific function could be called by any stored procedures inside my database.

I have no idea what kind of solutions I could use. I've learned that only 3 kinds of UDF are avalaible.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UDF always has to be side-effect free. That means that you cannot change data in a table from within a function.

If you are looking to call your logger from stored procedures, why not implement it as a stored procedure too?

Comment: I thought it's better as a function approach ! But if there's no solution, I'll do it as you suggest.
Thanks.